# Remap values in column headers based on dict & save it in a new dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel file provided from a user containing the data for import.
The headers in the file are different than those in my database.

In the first step I need to use a dict to remap the column headers to the real database names and then create a new dict containing rows as **values** and *new database names* as **keys**.

**some short example, with only 2 columns:**
key = header in the excel file
value = name of to column in the database

```
key_value_parse = {'Application Code': 'application_code', 'Long name': 'name_long'}
```

Example how the final dict should look like:

```
final_dict = [
              {'application_code': 20601, 'name_long': 'Item 1'},
              {'application_code': 20602, 'name_long': 'Item 2'},
              {'application_code': 20603, 'name_long': 'Item 3'},
              {'application_code': 20604, 'name_long': 'Item 4'},
             ]
```

Example excel file: The first row need to be skipped `skiprows=[0]`
[image: Example excel file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rename` on columns axis then `to_dict` to export your dataframe:

```
key_value_parse = {'Application Code': 'application_code', 'Long Name': 'name_long'}

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', skiprows=1).rename(columns=key_value_parse)
final_list = df[key_value_parse.values()].to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  name_long  application_code
0    Item 1             20601
1    Item 2             20602
2    Item 3             20603
3    Item 4             20604
4    Item 5             20605

>>> final_list
[{'application_code': 20601, 'name_long': 'Item 1'},
 {'application_code': 20602, 'name_long': 'Item 2'},
 {'application_code': 20603, 'name_long': 'Item 3'},
 {'application_code': 20604, 'name_long': 'Item 4'},
 {'application_code': 20605, 'name_long': 'Item 5'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First read the data using pandas library. Rename the columns using dictionary. And then add each row information as individual dictionary in your final list.

```
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
df.rename(key_value_parse, axis = 1, inplace = True)
final_list = []
df.apply(lambda x: final_list.append({"application_code":x['application_code'],'name_long':x['name_long']}), axis = 1)
```

However if your requirment permits...as a better solution, here we can see we are repeating column name in every dictionary..you can try something like

```
final_dict =  {'application_code': [20601,20602,20603,20601], 'name_long': ['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4']}
```